# Force Of Attraction Without Bounce

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recreational-mathematics

When programming animations controlled by mouse / touch gestures, I like to add some smoothness to the interaction. usually I work with position $q$ and velocity $p$ for the animation, and there is an attractor $q_a$, which is directly controlled by the gestures, to which the position is drawn to with force $a(q_a-q)$.  Now I wonder what functions $a$ work for this force of attraction, so that I have no bounce effect, given that there is some drag $d>0$ which reduces the velocity in each frame.

To put in terms of differential equations, I want to know for which functions (if any) $a:\mathbf{R}\to\mathbf{R}$ the solutions to $\dot{q} = p$; $\dot{p} = a(-q) - dp$ are monotonic and approach $0$ for any initial condition with $p(0)= 0$.

Comment: Is $q=x$? else what is $x$?

Comment: The idea is that you move e.g. the mouse, that is position $x$, and the animation ($p$, $q$) follows the mouse.  But there might be other forces than just the mouse, I just want to know if there is any sort of attraction in this setting which would make the animation follow the mouse without overshooting, or bouncing.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit confused, I tried to clear up the question and replaced $x$ by $q_a$, but in the end, I didn't want to use $x$, this should've been $p$ and $q$ (as it is now).

Comment: Do you specifically want a physics-based model, or are you okay with any motion path that will get the object to the target?

Comment: It doesn't have to be physics-based!  I usually take an attractor which is linear to the distance, which I think is also not existent in real world physics...